# Why do Japanese anime characters shout so much?

Tags: tropes, welcome-to-the-nhk

I would like to point out this incident from **NHK ni Youkoso** - Episode 21 (11:12 to 11:34).
The main character Sato is escorting his friend Yamazaki to a subway station to bid final adieu to him. Yamazaki is a game creator (gal games) and MC helps him to create one. I have written below a short piece of dialogue (writing it from the English subtitles) between the two at the subway station:

> **Sato**: Sorry
>
> **Yamazaki**: If you visit home, be absolutely sure you get in touch
>
> **Sato**: Sure..
>
> **Yamazaki**: See you around.
>
> **Sato (a bit panicked)**: Yamazaki..
>
> **Yamazaki**: Don't let the world beat you, Sato
>
> **Sato (this main character seems even more panicked and shouts in Japanese)**: You are not going home defeated, right?!
>
> **Yamazaki** *chuckles*.
>   ...
>   ..

Now my question to all the fellow members is, why does the character shout here? It seems a bit awkwardly and reluctantly placed. This is one instance which I have cited here but I have seen this sort of thing in other animes before. I can't exactly remember the names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, welcome to Anime & Manga!

Suddenly shouting is a trope used in a lot of media, not just anime & manga.

It is often used in the following scenarios:

- **In anger:** When a character reacts to a situation with rage, much like in real life, shouting can be expected to follow.
- **In fear or surprise:** Again similarly to real life, when taken by surprise, people often exclaim loudly almost reflexively.
- **For dramatic effect:** More often seen in media, when an important event or statement requires additional attention, it is often shouted to give it just that.

The conversation above in particular is likely for dramatic effect - I couldn't say for sure as I don't know the context of the whole show.

See [this page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuddenlyShouting) for more information.

Also related is [this question.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/what-is-the-purpose-of-characters-shouting-the-name-of-their-attack) Shouting the names of attacks naturally fits into the third option.

Comment: I agree it was probably for dramatic effect. Not only was this a dramatic scene, the character who yells, Satou, is high-strung and just tends to yell a lot and get worked up over things. This was extremely true in the manga and novel; less so in the anime, but still not out of character.