# Does Dio or Jotaro have to verbally stop time in order to stop time?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In some instances seen in the anime, Jotaro and Dio, stand users who both can stop time can stop time without having to verbally stop time, such as when Jotaro fights Josuke and stops time after Josuke's stand breaks his stand's guard and yet some other times they are seen having to verbally say it in order to stop time, like when Dio attempts to stop time but fails since Jotaro managaes to get his heart working again quick enough.

Does Dio or Jotaro have to verbally stop time in order to stop time?

Comment: Well, as you say they are both seen doing it without verbal cues. It's definitely **クール** when they shout it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two of them

> three if you count Diego from another universe

don't have to say "The World" whenever they want to stop time.

You can find the reason why they said "The World" to stop time on this question:
[What is the purpose of characters shouting out the name of their attack?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/what-is-the-purpose-of-characters-shouting-out-the-name-of-their-attack/2887#2887)

From the answer section, it's stated that,

> It's a tradition where it was intended for young audiences to yell the
> attack names with the character. The tradition began with Mazinger Z,
> which is considered the first Super Robot anime. The producers of the
> show felt that if the main character, Kouji Kabuto, shouted out the
> attack names each time the mecha did them, then it would give the
> target viewers, who were aged around 3 to 10 at the time, the ability
> to literally join along in the fun.
>
> The logic behind this is if the kids were to directly interact with a
> show they already liked, then they'd like it even more and would stick
> with the show in the long run. Needless to say, the strategy worked,
> and literally all other mecha anime in the '70s (sans First Gundam in
> late, late '79) copied the trend.
>
> Thus, the tradition was born and still anime shows, regardless of
> whether they are mecha themed or not, use it, regardless of their
> target audience.

From the user's answer, it's stated

> Also, It seems that it was also done to make the shows feel more
> intense. Something about the characters yelling their attacks just
> makes the action better.

From what you said

> when Dio attempts to stop time but fails since Jotaro manages to get
> his heart working again quick enough.

The reason why JoJo could reach Dio's head even though Dio had verbally said "The World" to stop the time is that JoJo had a new ability to stop time *at that time*, but not that much, just about milliseconds. To prove that, these are some clips where JoJo tried to move when Dio stop the time.

1. [0:10](https://youtu.be/oURw11sSjp4?t=10s)
2. [2:22](https://youtu.be/mO4z_2J2mmU?t=2m22s)

Here are some examples to prove that Dio/Jotaro didn't have to say "The World" to stop time

**JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Stardust Crusaders**

1. When Polnareff attacks Dio with Silver Chariot at [0:58](https://youtu.be/skjIgOAGa7I?t=58s)
2. When Polnareff met Dio for the first time at [1:39](https://youtu.be/UQP5jktm0GQ?t=1m39s)
3. When Hol Horse tried to kill Dio at [3:44](https://youtu.be/G6UsDWEwtH0?t=3m44s)
4. When the Stardust Crusaders tried to open Dio's coffin at [0:21](https://youtu.be/1NuB-Icu_kg?t=21s)
5. Chase scene where Dio tries to beat up Joseph [0:22](https://youtu.be/Z07GWchndjI?t=22s)
6. Scene 1 [0:23](https://youtu.be/mO4z_2J2mmU?t=23s)
7. Scene 2 [0:51](https://youtu.be/mO4z_2J2mmU?t=51s)

**JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Diamond Is Unbreakable**

1. Jotaro vs Josuke [4:17](https://youtu.be/QuTi6zYYuig?t=4m17s)
2. Jotaro vs Rat 1 [2:35](https://youtu.be/TlVDLb_FZ4w?t=2m35s)
3. Jotaro vs Rat 2 [3:25](https://youtu.be/TlVDLb_FZ4w?t=3m25s)